# SquarePointOfSaleSDK transaction id is nil

Tags: square, square-connect

I've build an iOS app that uses the iOS [SquarePointOfSaleSDK](https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS) which returns me a `Transaction Id` and nothing more. But sometimes (under really bad network connection) it returns nil instead of the `Transaction Id`, is this an expected behavior? How would I get the Transaction information afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior, due to the `transactionID` being generated on Square's servers (so if there's bad network connection or no network connection, it probably won't be generated and returned in time).

There will also be a `clientTransactionID` returned, which can be matched by calling `ListTransactions` and finding the `Transaction` with a `client_id` matching `clientTransactionID`.

Please find more information here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/point-of-sale#sccapiconnection